# session in jsp/struts

Tags: html, jsp, session, struts

I have 3 jsp, jsp1..jsp & jsp2.jsp have a button name "TEST", when user click on it - he gets forwarded to Test.jsp which dynamically changes depending on which jsp user has pressed TEST.

so depending on user where he comes from, I change the logic in action class to direct the user, for that I am passing sessions.

jsp1.jsp

```
<input type="hidden" name="jspType" value="M" property="jspType">
```

jsp2.jsp

```
<input type="hidden" name="jspType" value="C" property="jspType">
```

In the action class of my Test.jsp

TestAction.java

```
String jspTypeVariable = (String) request.getParameter("jspType");
```

later down in code

```
if(jspTypeVariable=="M")
{
system.out.println("Magic");
}
else if (jspTypeVariable=="C")
system.out.println("Cash");
```

==================================

It doesnt work? Any one help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare Strings with `==`. `==` tests if both objects are the same instance, not if their contents is the same. Use `if ("M".equals(jspTypeVariable))` instead.